# I need help getting the button 'b' in my program to print out the label 'result'

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter-button

I am creating a Mad Libs and I've gotten everything to work expect for the button 'b' to only show the label result when it is pushed. it instead shows it before any of the information in the texts boxes can even be put into the story.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

first = tk.Tk()
first.geometry('100x100')



def Story_one():

    top = tk.Tk()  
    top.geometry("600x600")    
    

    story1 = StringVar()
    name1 = StringVar()
    noun11 = StringVar()
    adjective11= StringVar()
    verb11= StringVar()
    adjective22 = StringVar()
    animal11= StringVar()
    verb22= StringVar()
    color11 = StringVar()
    Verbing= StringVar()
    adverb11= StringVar()
    number11 = StringVar()
    Time11= StringVar()
    color22=StringVar()
    animal22=StringVar()
    number22 = StringVar()
    silly1=StringVar()
    noun33 = StringVar()

    story1.set('This weekend I am going camping with '+name1.get()+ '. I packed my lantern, sleeping bag, and '+noun11.get()+ '. I am so '+adjective11.get()+' to '+verb11.get()+ ' in a tent. I am '+adjective22.get()+ 'we might see a '+ animal11.get()+ ', they are kind of dangerous. We are going to hike, fish, and '+verb22.get()+' . I have heard that the '+color11.get()+' lake is great for '+Verbing.get()+'. Then we will '+ adverb11.get()+ ' hike through the forest for'+number11.get()+Time11.get()+ '. if I see a '+color22.get()+animal22.get()+' while i am hiking, I am going to bring him home as a pet! At night we will tell '+number22.get()+silly1.get()+' stories and roast '+noun33.get()+ ' around the campfire!!')


    b= Button(top,text = 'Show Story 1', width = 20, command = story1.get())
    result = Label(top,text = story1.get(), textvariable=story1, wraplength=300)
    result.grid(row=18, column =1, padx= 10, pady =10,)

    display = Button(top, text = "Exit", width =10,command = top.destroy )   
    
    name = Label(top, text = "Enter a name").grid(row =0)
    e1 = Entry(top,justify = 'left', textvariable= name1)
    e1.grid(row=0, column=1)


    noun1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a noun").grid(row =1)
    e2 = Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable=noun11)
    e2.grid(row=1, column=1)


    adjective1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a adjective").grid(row =2)
    e3 = Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable= adjective11)
    e3.grid(row=2, column=1)


    verb1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a verb").grid(row=3)
    e4 =Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable=verb11)
    e4.grid(row=3, column=1)


    adjective2 = Label(top, text = "Enter a adjective").grid(row =4)
    e5 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable=adjective22)
    e5.grid(row=4, column=1)


    animal1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a animal").grid(row=5)
    e6 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable=animal11)
    e6.grid(row=5, column=1)


    verb2 = Label(top, text = "Enter a verb").grid(row=6)
    e7 =Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= verb22)
    e7.grid(row=6, column=1)


    color1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a color").grid(row =7)
    e8 =Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= color11)
    e8.grid(row=7, column=1)


    verb3 = Label(top, text = "Enter a verb ending in ing ").grid(row=8)
    e9 =Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= Verbing)
    e9.grid(row=8, column=1)


    adverb = Label(top, text = "Enter a adverb").grid(row=9)
    e10 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= adverb11)
    e10.grid(row=9, column=1)


    number1 = Label(top, text = "Enter a number").grid(row=10)
    e11 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= number11)
    e11.grid(row=10, column=1)


    time = Label(top, text = "Enter a measure of time").grid(row = 11)
    e12 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= Time11)
    e12.grid(row=11, column =1)


    color2 = Label(top, text = "Enter a color").grid(row =12)
    e13 = Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable= color22)
    e13.grid(row=12, column=1)


    animal2 = Label(top, text = "Enter a animal").grid(row=13)
    e14 = Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable= animal22)
    e14.grid(row=13, column=1)


    number2 = Label(top, text = "Enter a number").grid(row=14)
    e15 = Entry(top, justify = 'left', textvariable=number22)
    e15.grid(row=14, column=1)


    silly = Label(top, text = "Enter a Silly word").grid(row=15)
    e16 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable=silly1)
    e16.grid(row=15, column=1)


    noun= Label(top, text = "Enter a noun").grid(row=16)
    e17 = Entry(top, justify = 'left',textvariable= noun33)
    e17.grid(row=16, column =1)



    b.grid()
    display.grid()
    top.mainloop()



button1 = Button(first, text = 'Press to see story 1 ', command = Story_one)

button1.grid()

first.mainloop()
```

Comment: `command = story1.get()` is calling the function immediately, not when the button is pushed. The `command` argument should be a function reference, not a call to the function.